# Best ways to do POST/GET request from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get, fetch

I'm learning JavaScript. I want to perform GET and POST request from JavaScript to/from a Django Backend.

I was told that **AJAX is outdated**, that I should use a framework, like React, Angular or Vue. I'll start to learn React, but first I would like to know if theres a modern/prefered way to perform API request from JavaScript.

In [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/) "fetch" is mentioned. Could be this the way to go?

Comment: You've been misinformed regarding terminology.  AJAX is **not** "outdated".  If you want to make a request to the server in the background, AJAX is how you do that.  [The `fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is one way to perform an AJAX request.  And none of this has anything to do with React, Angular, or Vue.

Comment: "I was told that AJAX is outdated, that I should use a framework, like React, Angular or Vue." —  That makes no sense at all. Ajax is the act of making an HTTP request from JS. Frameworks like React, Angular and Vue are using to relate data to UIs inside the browser and frequently get that data by using Ajax.

Comment: "In this article "fetch" is mentioned. Could be this the way to go?" — `fetch` is an API for doing Ajax. So if the goal is to not do Ajax, then no, it isn't. (Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic here though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a JS Framework to do so, and Javascript has modern features that can help you a lot. In fact, I totally agree with the "fetch" of the article you pined, and I always go for this kind of request if I am in vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dylan